# When is a flat DB design acceptable

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, denormalization

When is it OK to abandon the wisdom of relational database design and revert back a flat table structure that incorporates no links, adding extra columns to add more data, when we should be creating a key to another table to store multiple rows?

I'm working on some ideas to discuss with a product management team. When I initially asked the question "Why are all these tables flat in nature?" I was told
"Read centric databases display better performance with a flat table structure."

I struggle with this explanation because a flat design presents so many barriers to progress down the road.

This flat table is not heavily indexed by default. Product design allows for customers to add columns to the table to store additional phone numbers as needed. That means the indexing is entirely on the customer; this is not something that is frequently an area of comfort for most customers.

Comment: What is the expected no of rows and columns in this table. You can create indexed views on this flat table to get some performance benefit. You must also check redundancy(density http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384.aspx) of data.

Comment: Additional columns have to be added in order to add more phone numbers because the design is not correctly normalised. If you add a new column you have to add a new index to get performance, and you cannot support relational integrity across multiple rows and columns. You also have to duplicate column constraints across multiple columns.

Comment: In case you are using Oracle, consider using [materialized views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/basicmv.htm). That way, you can have you cake (normalized data model) and eat it too (avoid JOINs). Depending on your particular needs, you _might_ achieve similar effect through [clustering](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tip_hash_index_cluster_table.htm).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_database

Answer (score 3):

"Read-centric databases display better performance with a flat table structure." This statement says the table will be used rarely/never for insert/update/delete operations. In that case, the table must be properly indexed to get good performance. Since there won't be any kind of joins, the table would be using a lot of filters and where clauses hence indexing is really important to be used appropriately.

This kind of scenario is usually used in data warehouses. When we design warehouses, we usually eliminate primary/foreign keys and use business primary keys. This is because of the huge database in warehouses.

Answer (score 1):

Never.

Whatever problem you think you are going to solve by ignoring relational database theory, you will only create many more intractable problems. Furthermore, the original problem that you attempt to avoid by ignoring relational theory will invariably be based on a misconception anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Almost always!
Your website almost never needs conventional database!

After 20 years of working as an IT admin with big and small projects I can say with confidence that over 90% of todays websites do not need DataBase AT ALL.
It's just another layer of obfuscation that most companies and people can do without.

Face the facts people. Most websites out there don't get a single hit in a day so talking about DataBase performance is quite silly when it comes to HUGE majority of websites today (2019).

That means that over 90% of these sites could and should switch to some flat file CMS/CMR like PageKit, Grav or Bludit (It's my personal favorite because of its minimalistic approach. It disdains flatDB and uses ordinary folders to contain articles in HTML files.)

I never did figure out why CMS leaders like WordPress and Joomla insist on complicating their default setup by forcing their users to use DataBase connection and configuration that's often the reason the site malfunctions. If and only when site actually needs some type of DB like for instance if it has many user accounts then DB is warranted. Still, most websites have only a hand-full user accounts.

Many times we see some site down because the DataBase engine is down or can't handle so many simultaneous connections while Apache or NginX web-servers are still up and running.

Don't just follow others blindly. Time to be brave and lead.